# Prettier glob matching multiple file types

Tags: node.js, npm, glob, prettier

I have added a `prettier` script in my `package.json` so I can run it as part of my  tests:

```
"prettier": "prettier --list-different \"**/*.{ts, js, css, scss, md}\""
```

I want all files from the above types to be checked by Prettier.
* `--list-difference` just prints out the files that are not prettified and returns an error code so it's convenient to run in CI.

When I run

```
$ npm run prettier
```

Prettier returns 0 results even though I know there are files that are not prettified.

I am not sure what's going on, can someone please help me understand what's wrong with my glob matching ?

(Running in Ubuntu 18.04 with bash)

Answer (score 18):

Found the issue.

In case anyone else is trying to match more than one file type, syntax is right but you cannot have spaces in the curly braces. So instead

```
"**/*.{js, ts, css, scss, md}"
```

It should be

```
"**/*.{js,ts,css,scss,md}"
```

This website helped me debug it easily:
https://globster.xyz

Comment: globtester no longer exists. I found https://globster.xyz useful